# GetMenuBarInfo() win32 function

Tags: winapi

I wanted to get the dimensions of a drop-down menu from the menu-bar. According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmenubarinfo) if I pass in `OBJID_CLIENT` to the `idObject` parameter of

```
BOOL GetMenuBarInfo(
  HWND         hwnd,
  LONG         idObject,
  LONG         idItem,
  PMENUBARINFO pmbi
);
```

I should be able to retrieve the `MENUBARINFO` structure of

> The popup menu associated with the window.

---

However *I don't believe there is a pop-up menu associated with a window*. Calling `GetMenuBarInfo()` with `OBJID_CLIENT` gives me zeros, calling `SetMenu()` (on a sub-menu on the menu-bar) gives me an `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error code. `TrackPopupMenu()` is the only documented way to display pop-up menus but it blocks.

Is the documentation wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `hWnd` needs to specify the window handle of menu bar, and the pop menu is visible.

This is usually used in Windows Hook. sample:

```
HHOOK hhook;
LRESULT CALLBACK myHookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CWPSTRUCT* lpcwps = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;
    BOOL ret = 0;
    if (code == HC_ACTION)
    {
        if (lpcwps->message == MN_GETHMENU)
        {
            MENUBARINFO minfo;
            minfo.cbSize = sizeof(MENUBARINFO);
            ret = GetMenuBarInfo(lpcwps->hwnd, OBJID_CLIENT, 0, &minfo);
            printf_rect(minfo.rcBar);
        }

    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And

```
hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)myHookProc, hInstance, GetCurrentThreadId());
```

This will hook the Winproc of system menu class `L"#32768"`, and get the menubar window when the after the pop-up menu has been visable.

Comment: What exactly should trigger the MN_GETHMENU messages? SendMessage() and GetMenuBarInfo() both trigger them but unless I use the HWND from FindWindowW(L"#32768",) I get garbage (i.e. top left: -858993460, -858993460. bottom right -858993460, -858993460)

Comment: `MN_GETHMENU` messages was triaggered in winproc of L"#32768" window instead of the main window. The sample is just to point out that `hWnd` needs to be specified as the window of menubar(L"#32768") instead of mainwindow.

Answer (score 2):

`TrackPopupMenu()` does not block your code from execution. It has message loop inside, this message loop processed popup menu messages *and* messages of your window.

For example, if your window is being repainted while showing menu caused by `TrackPopupMenu()`, you are able to find that menu using `GetMenuBarInfo` from your `WM_PAINT` handler. Same way with `WM_TIMER` or other messages, there's even dedicated `WM_ENTERMENULOOP` message.

Comment: Thanks, `TrackPopupMenu()` does indeed call my `WndProc()`. But I still get zeros from `case WM_MENUSELECT: GetMenuBarInfo(hWnd, ((LONG)0xFFFFFFFC), 0, &info);        printf_rect(info.rcBar);`. Should I be passing in a different `HWND` than I get from my `WndProc()`? I don't know how I can get at any other one.

Answer (score 2):

```
case WM_MENUSELECT:
    {
        HWND myhWnd = FindWindowW(L"#32768", nullptr);       
        GetMenuBarInfo(myhWnd, OBJID_CLIENT, 0, &info);
        printf_rect(info.rcBar);
    }
```

works. But I wouldn't have known how to get the name of the system menu class without out Drake's answer:

> hook the Winproc of system menu class `L"#32768"`.